Morphisms between modules over a Hopf algebra
Let $U$ be a Hopf algebra over a field $K$ and $M,N$ be $U$-modules. Then the set of all $K$-linear maps $\textrm{Hom}_{K}(M,N)$ has a canonical $U$-module structure given by
$$(u.f)(m) = \sum_{(u)} u_{1} f(S(u_{2})m) $$
for all $u \in U$, $f : M \to N$ and $m \in M$. (Equivalently, one can define the $U$-action by using the isomorphism $\textrm{Hom}_{K}(M,N) = N \otimes_{K} M^{*}$.)
Now let $\textrm{Hom}_{U}(M,N)$ be the set of all $U$-linar morphisms and $\textrm{Hom}_{K}(M,N)^{U}$ be the set of all morphisms invariant under the $U$-action, i.e. $f \in \textrm{Hom}_{K}(M,N)^{U}$ iff $u.f = \epsilon(u)f$ for all $u \in U$. (Here $\epsilon : U \to K$ is the counit map.)
We can easily check that $\textrm{Hom}_{U}(M,N) \subseteq \textrm{Hom}_{K}(M,N)^{U}$, and the converse also holds for some Hopf algebras such as $U = K[G]$ (group ring), $U(\mathfrak{g})$ (universal enveloping algebra) or $U_{q}(\mathfrak{g})$ (quantum enveloping algebra).
My question is, is the converse true for a general Hopf algebra $U$? For example, in the case of $U_{q}(\mathfrak{g})$ the proof goes by considering each generators $E_{i}, F_{i}, K_{i}$ separately, but this approach does not work for general $U$.

Yes. For a proof, see Lemma 4.1 in Hans-Jürgen Schneider, Lectures on Hopf algebras, notes by Sonia Natale. (The assumptions made on $k$ and $H$ in these notes are not used in the proof of that lemma.)

Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.
